# Expected Number of Flips to Obtain n heads and m tails

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to work through this problem from Sheldon's 10th Ed., 7.61.  It states

> A coin that comes up heads with probability *p* is continually flipped. Let *N* be the number of flips until there have been both at least *n* heads and at least *m* tails. Derive an expression for *E*[*N*] by conditioning on the number of heads in the first *n* + *m* flips.

Following their suggestion, if we let *H* be the number of heads obtained in the first $n+m$ flips, then $$E[N]=\sum_{j=0}^{n+m} E[N|H=j]P\{H=j\} = \sum_{j=0}^{n+m} E[N|H=j]\binom{n+m}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n+m-j}$$
Clearly, $n+m$ is the *minimum* number of flips required to obtain *n* heads and *m* tails, and if we assume that we have already obtained *h* heads, then we need $n-h$ more, while we must already have $n+m-h$ tails, so we need $m-(n+m-h)=h-n$ more.
However, at that point I am stuck; it seems to me that I have not reduced the complexity of the problem since in obtaining $n-h$ more heads, we may or may not obtain $h-n$ more tails, and vice versa.
I have access to the answer, and it states that $$\sum_{j=0}^{n+m} E[N|H=j]\binom{n+m}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n+m-j}=\sum_{j=0}^n \left(n+m+\frac{n-j}{p}\right)\binom{n+m}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n+m-j} + \sum_{j=n+1}^{n+m} \left(n+m+\frac{j-n}{1-p}\right)\binom{n+m}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n+m-j}$$
However, I cannot make the mental leap and see how $E[N|H=j]=\left(n+m+\frac{n-j}{p}\right)$ when $0≤j≤n$ and $E[N|H=j]=\left(n+m+\frac{j-n}{1-p}\right)$ when $n+1≤j≤n+m$.

Comment: Note that, with $n+m$ trials you must have completed one of your tasks and either you completed the other one on the last toss or you still have more to go on that one.

Comment: should say:  it's hard to follow what you wrote since you have $h$ as the summation variable but then your expressions depend on the undefined variable $j$.  Perhaps you meant $h=j$?

Comment: My apologies, when I worked it I used *h* as the number of heads, but Ross used *j*.  I will fix it.  Also, why would we necessarily be close to finishing a task? Suppose we had n+m-1 heads and only one tail?  We would still have at least m-1 tails to go?

Comment: If the number of Heads is $<n$ and the number of Tails is $<m$ then you can't have tossed the coin $n+m$ times.

Comment: Accordingly, I'd break the sum into three parts, according to $h<n$, $h=n$, $h>n$.

Comment: It is true that you must have completed at least one of the goals (at least n heads or at least m tails), but there is no guarantee of being near completing both.

Comment: Nobody, but you, said anything about being "near completing both".  You could have had only Heads in those first $n+m$ tosses.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being obtuse, but I don't see how further subdivision helps me express E[N|H = j].

Comment: Take $h<n$.  Then you have finished Tails but need $n-h$ more Heads.  We know how long we expect it to take to do that...

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought when you said that "with +
 trials you must have completed one of your tasks and either you completed the other one on the last toss or you still have more to go on that one" you were stating that both goals were nearly achieved.

Answer (score 2):

I finally understood what lulu was trying to tell me (see the comments on the original post).  If $j<n$, then we can be sure that $n+m-j>m$, so we have enough tails and we need only consider how many trials to get $n-h$ more heads.  This is a negative binomial random variable and therefore has an expected value of $\frac{n-j}{p}$, so the expected number of total flips – which is $E[N|H=j]$ – is $n+m+\frac{n-j}{p}$.

Likewise, if $j≥n$, then we can be sure that we have enough tails and we need only consider how many trials to get $h-n$ more tails.  The expected value of the additional number of flips is $\frac{j-n}{1-p}$ for a total number of flips $n+m+\frac{j-n}{1-p}$.

Thank you for your assistance.